# is it possible to minus padding

Tags: php, html, css, padding

As you can see on the picture my numbers are floating to the right, and I need to get them inside my div tag. I have tried to set all the values in my array to 0, but the numbers cannot get more to the left. As you see in the code now I have tried with -1, but that does not help either.

Does anybody have a clue what I could do?

HTML:

```
<div id="show">
<div class="numberheader">
    <p>Tal</p>
</div>
<ul class="latestnumbers" style="list-style:none;padding-top: 60px;">
    <?php include('response.php');?>
</ul>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
//echo "kuagdjagd";
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//include('session.php');

// Selecting Database
include 'dbconfic.inc.php';
$pad_left_values = array(0 => 19, 1 => -25, 2 => 1, 3 => -1, 4 => 38, 5 => -1, 6 => 38, 7 => -1, 8 => 38, 9 => -1, 10 => 38, 11 => 38, 12 => -1, 13 => 33, 14 => -1, 15 => 33, 16 => -1, 17 => 33, 18 => -1, 19 => -1, 20 => 33, 21 => -1, 22 => 33, 23 => -1, 24 => 33, 25 => -1, 26 => 33, 27 => -1, 28 => 33, 29 => 33, 30 => -1, 31 => 33, 32 => -1, 33 => 33, 34 => -1, 35 => 33, 36 => -1);
$colorArr = array(0=>"#029002", 1=>"#ff2700", 2=>"#ffaf32", 3=>"#ff2700", 4=>"#ffaf32", 5=>"#ff2700", 6=>"#ffaf32", 7=>"#ff2700", 8=>"#ffaf32", 9=>"#ff2700", 10=>"#ffaf32", 11=>"#ffaf32", 12=>"#ff2700", 13=>"#ff2700", 13=>"#ffaf32", 14=>"#ff2700", 15=>"#ffaf32", 16=>"#ff2700", 17=>"#ffaf32", 18=>"#ff2700", 19=>"#ff2700", 20=>"#ffaf32", 21=>"#ff2700", 22=>"#ffaf32", 23=>"#ff2700", 24=>"#ffaf32", 25=>"#ff2700", 26=>"#ffaf32", 27=>"#ff2700", 28=>"#ffaf32", 29=>"#ffaf32", 30=>"#ff2700", 31=>"#ffaf32", 32=>"#ff2700", 33=>"#ffaf32", 34=>"#ff2700", 35=>"#ffaf32", 36=>"#ff2700");

    // '?' er placeholders for variabler
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM numbertable ORDER BY num_id DESC LIMIT 9;");

    // execute prepared statement 
    $stmt->execute();

    // gør variabler klar:    
    $number = null;    
    $n_id = null;

    /* bind result variabler */
    $stmt->bind_result($n_id, $number);

    /* fetch values for hver row, her kun 1 row dog: */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $pad = ($number >= 1 && $number <= 36? $pad_left_values[$number]: $pad_left_values[0]);
        $col = ($number >= 1 && $number <= 36? $colorArr[$number]: $colorArr[0]);

            echo "<li><div style='padding-left: ".$pad."px; color: ".$col."'>$number</div></li>";
    }    

    // luk statement                        
    $stmt->close();

    // luk connection
    $mysqli->close();                   

?>
```

Comment: Your `ul` has padding already on it. Use `padding:60px 0 0 0` instead of just `padding-top:60px`

Comment: There is nothing like `-ve` in `padding`, better try giving `-ve` value to `left`.

Comment: It would be easier for people to help answer this if you created a JSFiddle or CodePen to illustrate the problem. Creating it might even help you to resolve it yourself. Concentrate the mind.

Comment: Also just FYI `ul`'s have default `padding`.

Comment: If you don't want `padding` for `ul` try giving `padding-left:0px;` to **ul**.

Comment: good point Niet the dark absol. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was: `padding:60px 0 0 0` instead of just *padding-top:60px*